# Django: make a list of column elements of selected rows

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm new on Django and SQL and I'm trying to solve some simple problems to start to understand them.

I have 3 models: Client, Product and Order. I want to list the products ordered by a client.

The models:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    .....

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    .....

class Order(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    .....
```

My solution was:

```
client= Client.objects.get(id=1) # target client
orders = client.order_set.all()
# or alternatively orders = Order.objects.filter(client=client)
list_of_orders=[order.product for order in orders]
```

My question: is there a better solution that uses some features of Django to get the list, instead of the for loop?

Answer (score 2):

From a deeper search in the Django documentation, I found that the for loop is actually used to solve the case of my question.

To avoid a db query each loop iteration, Django provides the methods **select_related()** and **prefetch_related()**.

Please see the two methods in [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can select only products from the queryset using `values_list()`, you can add the values which you want to return for example:

```
products = Order.objects.filter(client=client).values_list('product__product_name', flat=True)
```

the example apove will return a list of product names.

You can read how it works here [values_list in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Comment: Ashrof, thanks for your answer and link.  Unfortunately, the result I get is different from that I get using  for loop. The for loop produces a list of instances of <class 'orders.models.Product'> as a filter on Product. values or values_list, with 'product' as argument, produce a list of int (id).